# For about real Eigen vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there any complex hermitian matrix, which have real Eigen vector. If there any, please give such example. Thanks.

Comment: Observe that $I = I^*$ has the eigenvalue $1$ with eigenvectors $\langle 1, 0 \rangle$ and $\langle 0, 1 \rangle.$ Do you mean a nontrivial Hermitian matrix?

Comment: Of course. Pick any Hermitian matrix $A$ and create the block diagonal matrix $B$ with $1$ as the first block and $A$ as the second. Then $e_1$ is a real eigenvector.

Comment: Every real symmetric matrix is Hermitian with strictly real eigenvalues (and eigenvectors).

Comment: @Carlo, I mean here a hermitian matrix with such entries that atleast one of them is complex number,not real

Comment: @copper.hat, can you please explain it in detail!

Comment: @Subhajit: The answer below shows the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes. See for instance $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\ 0&1&i\\ 0&-i&1\end{pmatrix}$ which has an eigenvector in $(1,0,0)^t$. It is true that if a Hermitian matrix has a basis $(v_1,\cdots, v_n)$ of real eigenvectors, then the matrix is real, because the eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix are always real. This means that $A=PDP^{-1}$, where $P$ is the matrix having those eigenvectors as columns and $D$ is a real diagonal matrix. Therefore the entries of $A$ are the result of sums, mutliplications and quotients of real numbers.

Comment: Thanks!! But is this possible in even order matrix?

Comment: Yes, obviously. It is also possible for matrices which do not have trace equal to $3$.

Comment: Specially in order 2 case!!!!

Comment: No, for $2\times 2$ Hermitian matrices, one eigenvector is real only if the matrix is real. The non-trivial case is when there are two distinct eigenvalues, and in that case their eigenvectors must be orthogonal. However, in $\Bbb C^2$ the orthogonal of a real vector is spanned by a real vector.

Comment: Thanks for the logic!!!!